# How can you play a HDR video on Windows?

Tags: video-playback, hdr

I'm wondering: Do I need a certain player? Just playing a HDR video in MPC-HC on the attached TV doesn't work.

The video (HEVC MP4 with 10bit color/channel) isn't recognised as HDR, even in D3D fullscreen mode, so it looks wrong. The file works, if I let the TV play it from a directly attached storage, so that can't be it.

I'm using Windows 7 64bit and a Nvidia GTX 970. The TV is attached via the HDMI 2.0 output. The display mode is set to 12bit per channel RGB with full brightness range from the NV Control Panel.

Comment: If you need a special player depends on the codec used to create the video.  Once you identify the codec used we might be able to help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to have a display adapter that can send more than 8 bits per channel to the TV. Playing a video doesn't change that part in any way.

Comment: I would try VLC player... http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html